# WebKit: How to determine what elements are under a touch while dragging an animating div

Tags: javascript, multi-touch, css-animations

I'm trying to implement drag and drop for Mobile Safari.

Basically I want to drag a div via touch while it plays a looping CSS animation. I also want to determine when it's above a drop target and do something special.

I'm using **elementFromPoint** to determine what elements my div is being dragged over on **touchmove** events. However, the dragged div is always the topmost element. So before querying, I set it to **display: none**. However, this has the effect of resetting my animation every frame in which the touch moves.

How do I determine what I'm dragging above without resetting my CSS animation every time I query?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cy4Wv/) using touch events in WebKit.

**HTML** On every touchmove I move the **drag** div.

```
<div id='drop'>Drop here</div>
<div id='drag'>Drag me</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var drag = document.getElementById('drag');
var drop = document.getElementById('drop');

drag.addEventListener('touchmove', move, true);

function move(e) {
    var touch = e.changedTouches[0];
    drag.style.left = touch.pageX - 25 + 'px';
    drag.style.top = touch.pageY - 25 + 'px';

    drag.style.display = 'none';
    if (drop === document.elementFromPoint(touch.pageX, touch.pageY)) {
        drag.classList.add('in-drop-zone');
    } else {
        drag.classList.remove('in-drop-zone');    
    }
    drag.style.display = 'inline';
}
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    position: absolute;
}

div#drag {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-animation: sway 1s infinite alternate;
}

div#drop {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    left: 200px;
    top: 200px;
}

div#drag.in-drop-zone {
    background-color: yellow;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sway {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use drag events? http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Comment: It's supposed to not work on mobile... http://caniuse.com/#feat=dragndrop

Answer (score 0):

You could probably set `pointer-events: none` and then `pointer-events: auto`, but that seems pretty hacky. A better option is to have an intersection function:

```
var drag = document.getElementById('drag');
var drop = document.getElementById('drop');
var drop_bbox = drop.getBoundingClientRect();

window.addEventListener('touchmove', move, true);
window.addEventListener('mousemove', move, true);

function move(e) {
    drag.style.left = e.clientX - 25 + 'px';
    drag.style.top = e.clientY - 25 + 'px';
    var drag_bbox = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    drag.className = rectsIntersect(drag_bbox, drop_bbox) ? "in-drop-zone" : null;
}

 function rectsIntersect(r1, r2) {
  if (!r1 || !r2) return false;
    return r2.left < (r1.left+r1.width) && 
        (r2.left+r2.width) > r1.left &&
        r2.top < (r1.top+r1.height) &&
        (r2.top+r2.height) > r1.top;
};
```

Here is a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/duopixel/SvPpw/